# Most efficient way to batch update a peewee database from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, peewee

database looks like this:

```
date            value
2000-01-01      foo
2000-01-01      foo
2000-01-01      foo
2000-01-02      bar
2000-01-02      bar
2000-01-02      bar
2000-01-10      yyy
2000-01-10      yyy
2000-01-10      yyy
```

Pandas dataframe `MyDataframe` looks like this:

```
date            value
2000-01-01      new_foo
2000-01-02      new_bar
2000-01-10      new_yyy
```

As you might have guessed, I need the database to look like this:

```
date            value
2000-01-01      new_foo
2000-01-01      new_foo
2000-01-01      new_foo
2000-01-02      new_bar
ecc...
```

I could loop through `MyDataframe` and run a series of `.update`:

```
for date, value in MyDataframe:
    query = MyModel.update(value=value).where(MyModel.date == date).execute()
    query.execute()
```

My question is: is there a way to do this with just a single call to `execute()` (or any other way which is more efficient)? Something like `bulk_execute(array_of_queries)`?

Is there any way to feed the dataframe directly to .update()? Like this:

```
MyModel.update(value=MyDataframe.loc[MyModel.date]).execute()
```

This unfortunately doesn't work: the index passed to `.loc[]` is not the actual value but a `DateTimeField` object. Indeed, it gives this error:

```
KeyError('the label [<DateTimeField: MyModel.date>] is not in the [index]',)
```

The [documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#atomic-updates) suggests you can run actual code in the update function, providing examples such as:

```
Employee.update(bonus=(Employee.bonus + (Employee.salary * .1)))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try merging the dataframe and replace the original value column.

Comment: Please provide some code that would actually do the things you wrote down in your answer.